# node: http.request() behaviour in case of an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I observed some strange (at least from my point of view) behaviour of `http.request()` [Node.js API](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

```
  var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
      cb(null, res);
  });

  req.on("error", function (err) {
      cb(err, null);
  });
```

Now the request fails due to an error (`HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT`) and this causes the invocation of the error callback. Nevertheless the callback of `http.request()`gets invoked too.

In my opinion this should not happen if there is an error, like there should be no error if there is a (valid) response. Just one of them should get invoked - that would be what I expect. Here both of them are called which causes my further programm flow to be invoked twice...

Am I'm missing something or does that look strange to somebody else too?

Comment: http.request() - is http an Object of XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @messerbill, no I am talking about the Node.js ```http```api (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

Comment: oh sorry did not notice the tag....

Answer (score 0):

The callback is actually a listener for the "response" event. Therefore, if there is a response it will be called, even if that response is satisfactory or not.

The `HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT` means there was a problem with the response, but there actually WAS a response, and so the callback will be executed.